# TypeError: 'assign' called on an object that does not implement interface Location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

First of all, I apologize for my English and hope, you will understand my issue.

My once so well working script doesn't work anymore and I don't have a clue why.

It's a formular in wordpress, which used `reCAPTCHA` and an `address-check API` to send an email with specific infos.

The jQuery I am forced to use is: `1.12.4`

The form has the method `POST` and by clicking the submit button an `AJAX` function is called, which opens a `PHP script` that does things and send an email.

**The jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#welltherm-planer').submit(function(event){
        $("#ueberlagerung").attr("style","");
        $("#infotext").attr("style","");
        $("#infotext").html("");
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxFunktion();
    });

}); 


function ajaxFunktion(){

    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "adresscheck.php",
    data: { 
        firstname   : $('#firstname').val(),
        lastname    : $('#lastname').val(),
        street      : $('#street').val(),
        hno         : $('#hno').val(),
        zip         : $('#zip').val(),
        city        : $('#city').val(),
        country     : $('#country').val(),
        phone       : $('#phone').val(),
        email       : $('#email').val(),
        url         : window.location,
        g_recaptcha_response: $('textarea#g-recaptcha-response').val()
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#infotext").attr("style","background-color: #ff4400;color: #fff;padding: 8px 10px;");
        $("#infotext").html(data);

        if(data.indexOf("erhalten") >= 0){ 
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr("style", "display:none;");
            }
      }
      });

}
```

It seems that the `PHP script` doesn't even start. And if I click the submit button the browser console shows me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'assign' called on an object that does not implement interface Location. jquery.min.js:4:24986
```

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

What could be wrong?

Kind regards,
Katja

Comment: Seems that it comes from your `url: window.location` assignation. `location` is an object. Try using `url: window.location.href` instead.

Comment: Wow, thank you cFreed! So simple..